# Mongodb Index or not to index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

quick question on whether to index or not. There are frequent queries to a collection that looks for a specific 'user_id' within an array of a doc. See below -

```
_id:"bQddff44SF9SC99xRu",
participants: 
[
    {
        type:"client",
        user_id:"mi7x5Yphuiiyevf5",
        screen_name:"Bob",
        active:false
    },
    {
        type:"agent",
        user_id:"rgcy6hXT6hJSr8czX",
        screen_name:"Harry",
        active:false
    }
]
```

}

Would it be a good idea to add an index to 'participants.user_id'? The array is added to frequently and occasionally items are removed.

**Update**
I've added the index after testing locally with the same set of data and this certainly seems to have decreased the high CPU usage on the mongo process. As there are only a small number of updates to these documents I think it was the right move. I'm looking at more possible indexes and optimisation now.

Comment: Do you query on it regularly? Can you live with the increased write time against the performance gain of the query? These are generally the things that determine whether to use an index. What should not sway you is someones opinion here. Do what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to index? Do you have significant latency problems when querying? Or are you trying to optimise in advance?

Ultimately there are lots of variables here which make it hard to answer. Including but not limited to:

- how often is the query made
- how many documents in the collection
- how many users are in each document
- how often you add/remove users from the document after the document is inserted.
- do you need to optimise inserts/updates to the collection

It may be that indexing isn't the answer, but rather how you have structured you data.

Comment: So yes, there is a problem with very high cpu usage on the mongo process. The particular query that I have identified using Mongodb Compass appears to executed several times a second. I can see that it searches the entire collection (34,000 and growing) each time. A user will be inserted into a document at least once and any further additions or removals could happen 10 times per hour.